# Changing the shared_buffers value on a PostgreSQL node on Jelastic

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jelastic

Currently we are facing a `No unpinned buffers available` error on our PostgreSQL 9.4 node hosted on a Jelastic environment. The information found on Internet seems to indicate that the problem may be solved by setting a greater value for the `shared_buffers` variable in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf`, which is currently set to 128KB by default.

The thing is that we are, in fact, able to edit the postgresql.conf file via the Jelastic dashboard, and after saving the file, closing it, and reopening it, the new value seems to be set. However, after restarting the PostgreSQL node (so that the value is applied by the server), the `shared_buffers` value is restored to its default value, disregarding our setting.

Is the `postgresql.conf` file intended to be editable on Jelastic? Why is our change overwritten by the default value upon PostgreSQL node restart?

Comment: Is there a Jelastic autoconfiguration mark line in that file?

Comment: Yes, there is a `#Jelastic autoconfiguration mark.` line at the start of the `postgresql.conf` file. The Jelastic docs talk about the autoconfiguration mark in the context of [MySQL and MariaDB](https://docs.jelastic.com/database-configuration-files), but I haven't found that being mentioned for PostgreSQL. I was not aware of this autoconfiguration mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change any configurations in this file you need to delete the *#Jelastic autoconfiguration mark* string in order not to lose your custom settings.

Comment: Thanks. After deleting the line, the change I made in `postgresql.conf` was preserved after restarting the PostgreSQL node.

Comment: After changing the `shared_buffers` setting I noticed that my database backup scripts (which run daily via cron), no longer produce a valid PostgreSQL backup file (the size of the gzipped backup is 20 bytes, and the size of the backup file itself is 0 bytes.) I don't know whether this is just a coincidence or if the change on the `shared_buffers` setting is to blame. I cannot find any clue when running the scripts or on the PostgreSQL log files. I tried performing some standard Postgresql maintenance routines (e.g, vacuumdb), with no change. Any idea why this might be happening?